# How do I reduce the padding between the text hint and text line?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I have a TextInputEditText with a hint shown. I really do not like the amount of space between the hint and text line. I have tried setting the gravity to bottom but no luck.

```
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    android:hint="@string/email_hint"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/color_hint_grey"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/alternate_got_no1d"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: This is caused due to material theme of app, if you use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` ,This is not a clean solution , But it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reduce the height of a text box, you can use a [**dense** style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#height-variations), which will reduce the vertical padding within the text box

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       ....
       android:hint="Hint text"       
       style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense" >
```

Otherwise you can define (it requires the version 1.1.0) a custom style using:

```
  <style name="MyDense" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyThemeOverlayFilledDense</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyThemeOverlayFilledDense">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_dense</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_dense" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="android:paddingTop">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4dp</item>
  </style>
```

Here the results (with a default style and the custom style):

[image] [image]

Comment: but still hint is centered in collapsed state
Is there a way to bring it down in 1.1.0?

Comment: Dense doen't work well with the OutlinedBox

Answer (score 2):

add this to your **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText**:

```
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```

Comment: This worked, please tell how to give padding in activated state?

Answer (score 0):

To remove padding from all directions:

NOTE: paddingTop="0dp" is not recommended because inserted text would go over the title, so I would just play with the other attributes.

```
android:paddingStart="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp" 
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
```

Change the dp values according to your padding needs.
Keep in mind that if you use paddingLeft and paddingRight, it will have a bad appearance in devices that have rtl (right to left) language settings (like Arabic and Hebrew).