# Android TextInputLayout - no space below bottom line

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I've created text input using `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText`.
`TextInputLayout` should have gray background and `editText` line should be on the bottom without any margin. I tried with 0 margins and padding, but I didn't manage how to do that.

How it looks like:

[image: How it looks like]

What I need:

[image: What I need]

Comment: this will help you --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57740128/12553303

Comment: Please add your xml codes to the question too.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the standard `TextInputLayout` in the Material Components library.

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="Hint">

       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Text"/>

   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable file `bg_edittext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and go to your edittext, set

```
 android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext"
```

Comment: No reason to use a custom background in the TextInputEditText.